# Unpredictable Output in C++

Tags: c++

Here is a sample of source code

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
 int main()
{
    int i=2,a;
    a= pow(10,i);
    int b=0;
    b+=a;
    cout<<b;
    getch();
}
```

The ouput I expect is `100` as it is clear. But the compiler give `99` as output. Can anyone please explain what is the problem in the code and how it can b corrected to get `100` as output.

Comment: include `<iostream>`, not `<iostream.h>`.

Comment: no such issue......we can include .h header files also.......just in case if we dont write .h as u said just<iostream> then using namespace std ; needs to b included. :\

Comment: Take a look at the `pow` overloads: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/. Write your own speciatlization such as `int pow(int, int)`.

Comment: @Arun No, you cannot. It will fail on my compiler, and other recent compilers. It is not conforming C++. Don’t do it.

Comment: Oddly, on my MSVC2005 and WinXP setup, I get 100. What set up are you using?

Comment: @skizz-win7 64bit ....dev c++ compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
a = round(pow(10,i));
```

You can write the `round` function as:

```
int round(double r) {
    return (r > 0.0) ? floor(r + 0.5) : ceil(r - 0.5);
}
```

**NOTE:** `pow()` returns a double, so the best way to avoid such problem is to make `a` double, not `int`.

Answer (score 2):

`pow(10,i)` is 99.99999999999 then floored to integer a=99

You can create your own integer overloading of `pow(int,int)` also.

Good day.

Comment: but in usual maths 10^2 == 100, shouldn't pow return 100 rather than 99.99999....9999....9999.... ?

Comment: Because this is floating point math. The precision and exponential range floats. Need to overload integer version of pow for that

Comment: When you divide 1.0 by 3.0, number of iterations and precisions should be same for 1.0 divided by 2.0. So, any  simple division is like a repeating-decimal-number

Comment: Because cout makes a rounding rather than a flooring for your system/compiler settings. When you a=pow(), it makes a different thing

Answer (score 0):

Change your FPU rounding mode. Convert from round to zero to round to nearest. How you do this is not defined in the C standard so you'll need to use some intrinsic instruction or a bit of inline assembler.

Comment: Is this about CPU's fpu flags? (floor flag, ceiling flag, etc...)

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: Yes, on Intel IA32 FPU the rounding mode is defined in the FPU Control Word. If you want to be platform independent then you'll need to do some floating point magic that'll produce the correct result regardless of rounding mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ceil()` to round `double` value to the integer, just assigning is the same as `floor()` - it's truncating fractional part of floating point `double` number in your case (positive number). You may also find useful to get mathematical rounding - `floor(x + 0.5)` for positive `x`, `ceil(x - 0.5)` for negative one.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for [pow](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/c/math.h/pow.php) is as follows:

```
#include <math.h>
  double  pow (double x, double y)
  long    powl (long double x, long double y)
  float   powf (float x, float y)
```

So `pow(10, 2)` is a `double` and is perhaps being calculated as `99.99999999999`

So your line

`a = pow(10, i)` is storing `99.99999999999` into an `int`, so a **truncation** happens and `a` becomes `99`!

try `cout`'ing a after `a = pow(10, i);` to verify what I mean.

You could perhaps fix this by declaring `a` as a `long`. Worth trying...

Best would be to store the return value of `pow` as a `double` or `float`, not as an `int`!